# How to pass parameters between aspx pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have the following scenario : in tha page1.aspx i have an jtable containing a table and for each row there is a modify action. 
Once the user select the modify action the line become selected and the button **Modify line** turns enable. By clicking the modify button there is a redirect to page1.aspx&param1=1&param2=2 and goes to a new form with save or exit buttons.

Once the user from the new page click on save or exit - there is redirect back to page1.aspx.

Is there a way to pass back this 2 parameters param1 & param2 so I can fake the selected line back to the main page?

Comment: Redirect to mainpage.aspx&param1=1&param2=2 instead of mainpage.aspx.

Comment: Pass it as `URL params`, or store it in `session` variables

Answer (score 1):

SO you have Two parameters in the current query-string, and you want to send it back/to another page. Simply you can  do this by a redirect as like the Following:

```
string reDirectURL=String.Format("mainpage.aspx?param1={0}&param2{1}",
                                  Request.QueryString["param1"],
                                  Request.QueryString["param2"]);
Response.Redirect(reDirectURL);
```

Note : it will collect the current query-string parameters and send them to another page.

Answer (score 0):

### Add a condition in your mainpage page_load event handler to deal with parameters in URL. when you when you redirect back from detail page to main page, give some parameters like

mainpage.aspx?param1=1&param2=2

Add a condition in your main page page_load event handler to deal with parameters in URL.
If there are parameters in URL, highlight the line based on passed in parameters. if no parameters in URL, just reload the main page.